# Requiring HTML form date fields to be within certain time frame parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a few dates on an HTML form that I would like to constrain to certain parameters. To map it out a little:

Date A must not be in the future (this is already being accomplished via some javascript)
Date B must not be before A and must not be more than a day after A (so if A is 01/01/2020 then B can't be 01/03/2020)
Date C must not be before any other date and must not be more than a day after B
Date D must not be before any other date and must not be more than a day after C

I've tried a number of suggested methods but can't seem to get it working the way I'd like. I'm very new to this and would really appreciate any help.

I'm not sure that a copy of anything I've tried would be helpful here, but I can give some examples if it's needed...

the html is below:

```
        Date A:<input type="date" id="txtDate1" min="2020-01-01" name="A" required>

        Date B:<input type="date" id="txtDate2" min="2020-01-01" name="B" required>

        Date C:<input type="date" id="txtDate3" min="2020-01-01" name="C" required>

        Date D:<input type="date" id="txtDate4" min="2020-01-01" name="D" required>
```

Comment: Basically it sounds like B, C, and D each only have the possibility of being one single date.  So what's the point of them?  Once you pick A, you know what the rest are.  A, A+1, A+2, and A+3

Comment: You're right, I may be over thinking this... this an internally hosted form that I'm building to replace a federally required report. Essentially the user still needs to input those dates and I still need to lock those values to either A or A+1. But your comment is still helpful... I may have been thinking about it the wrong way.

Comment: Well, you said you already have it working for limiting what A is, right?  So don't even _have_ fields for the other ones.  Then in your PHP code (you've tagged this with `PHP`, so I assume you're submitting this as part of a form) you just create the other values as needed be incrementing A by one day.

Comment: you're exactly right, that's how I should/would like to do it, Unfortunately the user needs to physically report the dates for these purposes.

Comment: Okay.  Well since you say that you already have JavaScript that is restricting A from being in the future, I'm going to go ahead and assume that you can figure out how to check/enforce that B is A+1, etc.  If not, you should include that JavaScript that you already have.

Comment: Yeah I think I've got it, I was making this more difficult than it needed to be - Thanks for the help!